# XML adding attribute

Tags: php, xml

I want to add two attributes onto an element that looks something like this:

```
$tutTag->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createElement("Port", $serv->STMPPort)
)->setAttribute("type","int")->appendChild->setAttribute("y","l");
```

In this case, "type" and "int" get added just fine, but the second set "y" and "l" do not get added. How do i fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to remove second ->appendChild witch is reference to probably unknown attribute.

Comment: if i do: $xmlDoc->createElement("Port", $serv->STMPPort))->setAttribute("type","int")->setAttribute("y","l"); then i get the following error: Call to undefined method DOMAttr::setAttribute() in.. any other ideas? is this what you meant?

Comment: Could you write down XML you'd like to get as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add it to a variable first.

```
$childTag = $xmlDoc->createElement("Port", $serv->STMPPort);
$childTag->setAttribute("type","int");
$childTag->setAttribute("y","1");

$tutTag->appendChild($childTag);
```